# Axios in react-native returns empty array of data but POST man returns some data

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, axios

[image: My POSTMAN request]I have been working on a restaurant app and using Yelp as an API source.
I am using Axios as the request rather than fetch.
**I am returned with a empty array when I use the location as 'delhi' which is a valid location because I get proper response with the POSTMAN**

**yelp.js**

```
    const axios = require('axios');

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses',
  headers: {
    Authorization:
      'Bearer VALID KEY(working on POSTMAN)',
  },
});
```

**screen.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import SearchB from '../reusableC/SearchB';
import yelp from '../api/yelp';

const Search = () => {
  const [string, setString] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const searchApi = async () => {
    const response = await yelp.get('/search', {
      params: {
        limit: 50,
        location: string,
      },
    });
    setResults(response.data.businesses);
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <SearchB
        style={styles.fontS}
        string={string}
        onTermChange={newString => setString(newString)}
        onTermSubmit={() => console.log(results)}
      />
      <Text> Searched :</Text>
      <Text> {results.length}</Text>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: '400',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 55,
          left: 100,
          right: 10,
        }}>
        {string}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fontS: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

export default Search;
```

**when I console log the results**

**[ ]** *is returned*

I tried to make request via Postman and it returned valid data unlike in the Application.

Comment: Could you show your request from POSTMAN?

Comment: I have uploaded it ,have a look

Comment: Can I know at what point you are calling the searchApi method?

Comment: Thank you so much , this hint of yours , I figured out 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually calling the method, so the API call does not initiate. You can use useEffect hook to fetch data by calling this method as follows.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import SearchB from '../reusableC/SearchB';
import yelp from '../api/yelp';

const Search = () => {
  const [string, setString] = useState('');
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchApi = async () => {
      const response = await yelp.get('/search', {
        params: {
          limit: 50,
          location: string,
        },
      });
      setResults(response.data.businesses);
    };
    searchApi();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <SearchB
        style={styles.fontS}
        string={string}
        onTermChange={newString => setString(newString)}
        onTermSubmit={() => console.log(results)}
      />
      <Text> Searched :</Text>
      <Text> {results.length}</Text>
      <Text
        style={{
          fontSize: 20,
          fontWeight: '400',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 55,
          left: 100,
          right: 10,
        }}>
        {string}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fontS: {
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});

export default Search;
```

More about fetching data with hooks -> https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data